# Single pole switch with pilot

Tags: wiring

I installed a new single pole switch with pilot. Now he pilot of the new installed switch is on all the time. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: Can you post a picture of the wiring?  Give us a link in the comments, and one of us will wire it into the post for you until you get the reputation to do it yourself.

And Welcome!

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange.  First, your question is *welcome*.  Due to the unique editorial style of this platform, when we see questions that have been asked and answered before, we redirect to that Q&A.  If you feel that Q&A doesn't answer your question, feel free to hit "share edit **reopen**" (just below your question) and you can reopen and/or edit to state more clearly how your question is different.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, you have the hots reversed.  In the example clip below, the wires on the **Common** and **A1** terminals reversed.

[image: pilot switch]

Comment: Of course, that's the drawing of what he *has*, not what he *wants*.

Comment: I'm more confused now, is the diagram the right way or should I reverse the two wires?

Comment: @Bumpa - if your switch is like the one in the picture, you have two hots and a neutral on the switch, and I think you have the one that belongs on the common on the A1, and the one that belongs on the A1 on the common.

Comment: Going to switch the wires this week end, wish me luck - thanks everyone!